# How can I add high and low voltage signals to a high voltage DC offset?

Tags: signal, circuit-design, high-voltage, summing

It's only a theorethical question, since I'm not really going to build this circuit... I'm just curious, that's all. 
Anyway, thats my question!

I have these signals:

3 kHz, 1V (peak)

20 Hz, 100V (peak)

(DC offset is 70 V)

Since I doubt it would be impossible to add them (only impractical, I guess), I was wondering: 
how can I create a single signal out of those parameters?... Or better: 
Is there a "standard" method do such things when op-amps cannot be used?

EDIT: 
Thanks for your answers: each one is a different approach to solve the problem, so thank you, really!

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how acceptable it is for one signal to back-drive the others.  In the worst case, you isolate the AC signals each with their own series inductor and capacitor.  These would be narrow band filters to pass only the specific frequency (3 kHz and 20 Hz in your case).

The DC would be isolated with a "large" series inductor.  This would let the DC pass, but have sufficiently high impedance at 20 Hz to not attenuate that signal much.  The 3 kHz signal will see much higher impedance, so anything that works for the 20 Hz signal will work for the 3 kHz signal.

Comment: Wow, I never thought of using inductors and capacitors to sum signals instead of filtering them. Actually... this makes so much sense, now that I think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a transformer with the secondary in series with the DC source. This will superimpose an AC signal on top of the DC level. You can feed the primary from a ground referenced AC signal too.

Comment: If I use a transformer, and the input frequency is tunable, do I need a high-pass to not burn the transformer if the input frequency is below the coupled frequency of the transformer?

Comment: I have no clue what you mean. Maybe raise this properly in a new question?

Comment: Thanks, I did now. https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/478347/how-can-i-add-mhz-high-voltage-signal-to-a-high-voltage-dc-offset

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers are perfectly correct, you should keep in mind that building a high-voltage amplifier to do the job is not Real Hard as long as the load currents aren't too high. Your relatively low frequencies help in this regard. A simple high-voltage MOSFET and a normal op amp will do the job if you're willing to do some work on stability and frequency response.

And for 14 bucks you can get [an op amp](https://www.apexanalog.com/resources/products/pa340u.pdf) from Apex Microtechnology which will give you 300 volt swings. In your case you'd need asymmetric power supplies, like +250 and -50, but that's hardly impossible.